# Convert Java MessageDigest code snippet to C#

Tags: java, c#

The java code below generates a SHA-256 hash of the input **msg**, using the **key**. However, all my attempts to write code that does same operation in C# have not yielded the same results given same input. I would need help getting the C# equivalent as I have tried a lot already with little success.

I think I've been able to translate most of the code into C# correctly, apart from the part which updates the digest (**m.update()**), first with the key, then later with the message before hashing.

**JAVA CODE**

```
public static String generateHash256Value(String msg, String key) {
    MessageDigest m = null;
    String hashText = null;
    System.out.println("Value to hash::::::::::" + msg);
    byte[] actualKeyBytes = HexToByte(secret_key);

    try {
        m = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        m.update(actualKeyBytes, 0, actualKeyBytes.length);

        try {
            m.update(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, msg.length());
        } 

        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        hashText = new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16);

        if (hashText.length() < 64) { //must be 64 in length
            int numberOfZeroes = 64 - hashText.length();
            String zeroes = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfZeroes; i++) {
                zeroes = zeroes + "0";
            }
            hashText = zeroes + hashText;
        }
    } 

    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    hashText = hashText.toUpperCase();
    return hashText;
}

public static byte[] hex2Byte(String str) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) Integer
                .parseInt(str.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16);
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

**C# CODE** (attempt)

```
    private static string DoSpecialSha256Hash(string message, string key)
    {
        String hashText = null;
        Console.WriteLine("Value to hash::::::::::" + message);
        byte[] keyByte = hex2Byte(key);

        Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

        var hashAlgo = new SHA256Managed();

        var messageBytes = encoder.GetBytes(message);
        var toDigest = Combine(keyByte, messageBytes);

        hashText = ByteToString(hashAlgo.ComputeHash(toDigest, 0, message.Length));

        if (hashText.Length < 64)
        { //must be 64 in length
            int numberOfZeroes = 64 - hashText.Length;
            String zeroes = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfZeroes; i++)
            {
                zeroes = zeroes + "0";
            }
            hashText = zeroes + hashText;
        }

        hashText = hashText.ToUpper();
        return hashText;
    }

    public static byte[] HexToByte(String hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                .ToArray();
    }

    private static string ByteToString(byte[] buff)
    {
        string sbinary = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
        {
            sbinary += buff[i].ToString("X2"); // hex format
        }
        return (sbinary);
    }

    private static byte[] Combine(params byte[][] arrays)
    {
        byte[] rv = new byte[arrays.Sum(a => a.Length)];
        int offset = 0;
        foreach (byte[] array in arrays)
        {
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(array, 0, rv, offset, array.Length);
            offset += array.Length;
        }
        return rv;
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Where exactly is ypour problem? The most of this code should work for C# also. Stack is no code-service or translater, so please be more specific on your actual problem. Which line do you have problems with?

Comment: Thanks @HimBromBeere; I have added more details now, including what I've been able to do in C#, which did not give me expected results.

Any help like explaining the effect of MessageDigest.update() in Java and how I could logically replicate that in C# would go a long way. Thanks.

Comment: @HafizAdewuyi did you get any solution of this problem ?

Comment: No @EhsanHafeez I did not. I ended up solving the problem in another way entirely.

Comment: Hi, how did you slove this